# getting post data to paramater

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, webhooks

How do I get the data that is sent as post and set them as a parameter

```
API data will send
[APItype] => UpdateSend
[Date/Time] => 2016-01-10 00:00:00 
[initit_by] => John_admin
[NewList] => 1
[contact] => Array
    (
        [id] => 0001
        [email] => Patron-email@test.com
        [first_name] => Patron
        [last_name] => t=Test
    )
```

I would like to have the following:

```
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
             $APItype => UpdateSend;
             $id =  0001;
             $email => Patron-email@test.com;
             $first_name => Patron;
             $last_name => t=Test;
```

I thought I could just do the following to parameterize:

```
 $email=['contact']['email'];
```

That didn't work.

Comment: have tried like $_REQUEST['contact']['email']

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting post parameters then you can get those parameters like:

```
$contact = $_POST['contact'];    

$APItype => $_POST['APItype'];
$id = $contact['id'];
$email => $contact['email'];
$first_name => $contact['first_name'];
$last_name => $contact['last_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Jigar has said, you may also access them through the [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) superglobal, [filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) or one of it's derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extract` function. http://php.net/extract

```
$variables = extract($_POST);
```

Note: As the PHP docs says, you shouldn't use this on untrusted data,  user input. Be careful.